# Find the mass of the density

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

> Find the surface integral of the density $p = k\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ over the surface $z = 4-2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, z\in [0,4]$

$\phi(r,t) = (r\cos(t),r\sin(t),4-2r)$

$$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} = (\cos (t),\sin (t),-2) $$

$$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = (-r\sin (t),r\cos (t),0)$$

$\Rightarrow  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}  \times  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v} = (2r\cos(t),2r\sin(t),r)$

$\Rightarrow || \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}  \times  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v} || = 5r^2 $

$$\therefore \int_S p = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 r(4-2r)5r^2 dr\, dt$$

$$ ... = 32\pi $$

Can I check if what I have done is correct? (This isn't homework — It's just on a question sheet with no answers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice some problems. It is not clear what you are doing: in a flux, you have a surface and the density is a vector field, not a scalar. Maybe what you want is the surface integral of the density?

Even without clearing the above issue, there are some obvious problems:

1. The surface has $0\leq r\leq 2$ (and not $ 4$).
2. You seem to be integrating the dot product of the normal vector with the parametrization of the surface. This makes no sense.
3. This is a repetition of 2, but it should be obvious: you are not using the density.

---

**After the edit:** You are still making up stuff inside the integral, and missing at least part of your density. You have 
$$
\iint_S p\,dS=\iint_A\,p\,\left\| \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial u}  \times  \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial v} \right\|\,dA
=\int_0^2\int_0^{2\pi}kr(5r^2)\,dt\,dr
=10k\pi\int_0^2r^3\,dr
=40k\pi.
$$

Comment: Yes I think you're correct in that I have to find the integral of the density actually - I have adjusted my question accordingly.

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up. It makes sense now.